# JavaScript/jQuery: global variable inexplicably being reset, causing menu contraction issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables

http://jsfiddle.net/VhjR7/1/

When you click the **my lists** menu once, it expands, but if you click it again, it doesn't contract.

The problem is `listsExpanded` being inexplicably reset to `false` after it is set properly to `true` by `listsExpand()`. This causes the check within `$('#mid-wrap').delegate()` to inappropriately call `listsExpand()` again, instead of `listsContract()` like it should.

I can't figure out where or why this reset is occurring, but I think it has something to do with the sticky light blue menu functionality. Before I started removing and replacing this blue bar after scrolling to [fix an IE7 bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698990/ie7-cant-get-menu-to-stick-to-top-of-page), there was no issue with expansion/contraction of the little white menu.

Any ideas on what's causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `hover` event does not support both function arguments (in and out) when used with `.delegate()`.  You will need to use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead of `hover`.

Change to this:

```
$('#mid-wrap').delegate('#lists', 'mouseenter', function() {
    listsMouseIn = true;
}).delegate('#lists', 'mouseleave', function() {
    listsMouseIn = false;
});
```

FYI, if these HTML objects are static, not added dynamically, you could significantly simplify your code by using direct event handlers on that actual objects rather than .delegate and just stopPropagation() when you've processed the click.  Then, you'd see the click first in the object and wouldn't be processing the same click multiple times causing you to need all these global flags to keep track of state.

You could also just use the visibility of the object as your detection mechanism for whether the menu is open/closed too rather than a global variable.

Comment: Thanks so much. Testing the visibility of the object was actually my original approach, and I ran into the same issue. Also, the HTML objects unfortunately have to be added dynamically because of an IE7 bug. But this works--I had no idea that the click was being processed more than once.

Answer (score 1):

The first part of your hover handler (with `listsMouseIn = true;`) never actually fires so whenever you click, your `$('body').mouseUp()` handler assumes that you are not hovering the lists button, and therefore hides the menu just for the `$('#mid-wrap').delegate(...)` handler to show it again milliseconds later.

Replacing

```
$('#mid-wrap').delegate('ul#lists', 'hover', funcIn, funcOut);
```

with

```
$('#mid-wrap').delegate('ul#lists', 'mouseover', funcIn).
               delegate('ul#lists', 'mouseout', funcOut);
```

seems to do the trick.